# Why is this haskey() condition always false?

Tags: dictionary, if-statement, julia

I start out with a list of word counts:

```
julia> import Iterators: partition
julia> import StatsBase: countmap
julia> s = split("the lazy fox jumps over the brown dog");
julia> vocab_counter = countmap(s)
Dict{SubString{String},Int64} with 7 entries:
  "brown" => 1
  "lazy"  => 1
  "jumps" => 1
  "the"   => 2
  "fox"   => 1
  "over"  => 1
  "dog"   => 1
```

Then I want to compute the no. of ngrams per word and store it in a nested dictionary. The outer key would be the ngram and the inner key the word and inner-most value is the count of the ngram given the word.

I've tried:

```
ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
for (word, count) in vocab_counter
    for ng in ngram(word, 2) # bigrams.
        if ! haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng)
            ngram_word_counter[ng] = Dict{String,Int64}()
            ngram_word_counter[ng][word] = 0
        end
        ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += 1  
    end
end
```

And that gives me the data structure I need:

```
julia> ngram_word_counter
Dict{Tuple,Dict} with 20 entries:
  ('b','r') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('t','h') => Dict("the"=>1)
  ('o','w') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('z','y') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('o','g') => Dict("dog"=>1)
  ('u','m') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('o','x') => Dict("fox"=>1)
  ('e','r') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('a','z') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('p','s') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('h','e') => Dict("the"=>1)
  ('d','o') => Dict("dog"=>1)
  ('w','n') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('m','p') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
  ('l','a') => Dict("lazy"=>1)
  ('o','v') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('v','e') => Dict("over"=>1)
  ('r','o') => Dict("brown"=>1)
  ('f','o') => Dict("fox"=>1)
  ('j','u') => Dict("jumps"=>1)
```

But notice that the values are wrong:

```
('t','h') => Dict("the"=>1)
('h','e') => Dict("the"=>1)
```

should have been:

```
('t','h') => Dict("the"=>2)
('h','e') => Dict("the"=>2)
```

Since the word the appeared twice.

After a closer look, it seems like the `haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng)` is always false =(

```
julia> ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
for (word, count) in vocab_counter
    for ng in ngram(word, 2) # bigrams.
        println(haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng))
    end
end
```

[out]:

```
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Why is this `haskey()` condition always false?

Comment: Perhaps you want `ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count` instead of `ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += 1`

Comment: And the `false` values are because, well, the bi-grams are unique in this sentence (without word repetition)

Comment: Lastly, the `false` values are also because nothing is inserted into `ngram_word_counter` in this statement (only the `false` is printed)

Comment: Thanks @DanGetz `+= count` is the right answer =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR : It should be `ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += count` instead of `ngram_word_counter[ng][word] += 1`.

Adding just `1` neglects multiple contribution by a word appearing several times. The number of times the word appears is encoded in `vocab_counter` values which go into variable `count` in the `for` loop. Therefore the increment should be by `count`.

The later debug check is ineffective, and as often is the case, the debugging code's bugs confuse the problem. The intended check was probably:

```
julia> ngram_word_counter = Dict{Tuple,Dict}()
for (word, count) in vocab_counter
    for ng in ngram(word, 2) # bigrams.
        println(haskey(ngram_word_counter, ng))
        ngram_word_counter[ng] = 1
    end
end
```